# Docker - Copy files from external locations on host machine into containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu, centos, dockerfile, redhat

I need to test out my teams software on a couple different OS types and I decided to leverage Docker to help.

What I essentially want to do is have a tree of our repo checked out in some central location. I then want have several containers of different os types that all copy that git tree into their root folder when they are built. The reason for this is that I want all containers testing the same patch of software always.

Here is how I set up my docker container directory structure:

```
docker_containers/
    GIT_TREE/
    container_ubuntu14/
        git_tree/ (symbolic link to ../GIT_TREE)
        build.sh  (docker build commands specific to this os type)
        Dockerfile
        run.sh (docker run commands for use post build)
    container_ubuntu18/
        git_tree/ (symbolic link to ../GIT_TREE)
        build.sh  (docker build commands specific to this os type)
        Dockerfile
        run.sh (docker run commands for use post build)
    container_centos7/
        git_tree/ (symbolic link to ../GIT_TREE)
        build.sh  (docker build commands specific to this os type)
        Dockerfile
        run.sh (docker run commands for use post build)
```

So as you can see, each container type has a symbolic link pointing back to the main directory where my git tree is checked out. For each instance, in the `Dockerfile` there is a line `COPY git_tree /`. I try copying the symbolic link to the root dir of the new container and I get the following error everytime:

```
COPY failed: stat /home/user/docker_fs/tmp/docker-builder474024999/home/user/docker_containers/GIT_TREE: no such file or directory
```

Comment: IIRC Docker refuses to copy things from outside the current directory tree anyway. A simple but crude workaround is to copy the things you want to `ADD` or `COPY` into the current directory tree temporarily.

Comment: With your layout, perhaps construct each `Dockerfile` so you can `docker run subdir`

Answer (score 0):

Should it be GIT_TREE instead of GIT-TREE?

Comment: No sorry, that name is irrelevant I just needed a placeholder name for for my project

Comment: Your error log showing that the path it is looking for is GIT-TREE while your actual folder name should be GIT_TREE, perhaps there is a typo somewhere in your code that type the path incorrectly.

Comment: the name GIT_TREE was just a random thing i typed in since I did not want to write my projects actual name. I think the issues is that docker cannot follow the link correctly